# API's not shown but when I create a new one, it's already exist

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I migrated the WSO2 to another server. I copy the file of WSO2 and then copied the database.
I edit the file `deployment.toml` into new server. I run the publisher but no one API is shown. When I try creating a new one like the old server. It says, "API's already exist".
Do you have any solution about this? How to show the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using APIM 3.2+ version try adding the following to the `deployment.toml` and restarting the server.

```ini
[indexing] 
enable = true 
re_indexing = 1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, now the APIS is showing